# Result is different between Phoronix test suite and openssl speed

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, speedtest, stress-test

I have the result from phoronix test suite openssl 3.1.0 and openssl 3.1.0 from phoronix folder. The result is different between phoronix and openssl. I don't understand how the value is calculated.

My test script openssl speed `-multi 128 -seconds 30 -evp aes-256-gcm`

Output:

```
evp 22004797.19k 56503839.78k 137950217.82k 191126712.25k 226754791.29k 230415287.36k
```

....

```
Phoronix-test-suite benchmark openssl
```

Output:

```
Algorithm: AES-256-GCM:
535489700390
536565824720
535783063080

Average: 535946196063 byte/s
Deviation: 0.10%
```

Results Definition.
I understand correctly, phoronix gets the result from #*RESULT*# in the EVP template, the result from openssl aes 256 8k 226754791.29k, but phoronix gets 535783063080 byte/s​. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--Phoronix Test Suite v10.8.4-->
<PhoronixTestSuite>
<ResultsParser>
<OutputTemplate>rsa 4096 bits 0.000632s 0.000010s   #_RESULT_# 101133.8</OutputTemplate>
<LineHint>rsa 4096 bits</LineHint>
<ResultScale>sign/s</ResultScale>
</ResultsParser>
<ResultsParser>
<OutputTemplate>rsa 4096 bits 0.000632s 0.000010s   111.1 #_RESULT_#</OutputTemplate>
<LineHint>rsa 4096 bits</LineHint>
<ResultScale>verify/s</ResultScale>
</ResultsParser>
<ResultsParser>
<OutputTemplate>sha256          773058.94k  2674506.65k  #_RESULT_# 15092842.84k 20350306.99k 20835702.10k</OutputTemplate>
<LineHint>sha256</LineHint>
<ResultScale>byte/s</ResultScale>
</ResultsParser>
<ResultsParser>
<OutputTemplate>sha512          773058.94k  2674506.65k  #_RESULT_# 15092842.84k 20350306.99k 20835702.10k</OutputTemplate>
<LineHint>sha512</LineHint>
<ResultScale>byte/s</ResultScale>
</ResultsParser>
<ResultsParser>
<OutputTemplate>evp           17892198.62k 39185960.77k 80741276.16k 94270918.66k #_RESULT_# 103464173.57k</OutputTemplate>
<LineHint>evp</LineHint>
<ResultScale>byte/s</ResultScale>
</ResultsParser>
</PhoronixTestSuite>
```